# Keep items in ArrayList

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I'm working on a class which is a view for a backend-class and needs to display some of the backend-classes properties.

```
public abstract class AGenericNodeView{
    private ANode fObject;  
    private ArrayList<TInputView> fInputs = null;

    public AGenericNodeView(){
        super();
        this.fInputs = new ArrayList<TInputView>();
    }


    private void getInputs(){
        int num = fObject.getNumInputs(); //Number of inputs
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            this.fInputs.add(new TInputView());
            this.fInputs.get(i).doSth();  
        }
        //fInputs has now the size num which is greater than 0. 
    }    

   //later I call:
   public draw()
   {
      //...
      log(this.fInputs.size()); //output fInputs.size()
      // and it is 0. Always. 
   }


}
```

I wonder, if there is a way, to keep the Objects I create in `getInputs()` persistent, so that the list is not empty, when needed in `draw()`?

Comment: Add the relevant code where you use it.

Comment: Are you sure that you call getInputs()? That you call getInputs() and draw() on the same instance? Because it should be "persistent".

Comment: "*and it is 0. Always.*" => it seems that `draw` is called before `getInputs` then... Only other possibility is if you have two different threads executing `draw` and `getInputs`.

Comment: Or two different objects...

Comment: What is value `fObject.getNumInputs()` returns in your `getInputs()` method?

Comment: can you make fInputs as static?

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran that's what I was thinking too. If `fObject` is empty, then `fInput.size` will be 0

Comment: @Windle, no need to be empty, if it return `1` also, it won't execute the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of suggestions:

1. Use a debugger.
2. Log `num` in `getInputs`
3. Log `System.identityHashCode(fInputs)` in `getInputs` and in `draw` and verify they are same.

Comment: well. I found out, that I'm working with two different Objects of the containing class - I will try to resolve this and maybe refer to you guys later. Thank you a lot!